# Want to print triangle using while loop in T-SQL SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to print triangle using T-SQL while loop.
but i am not getting the correct format of output.
here is the code

```
declare @n int = 5 --number of lines
declare @i int=0
while (@i < @n)
    begin
        declare @j int=0
        while (@j <= @i)
            begin
                print '* '
                set @j = @j + 1
            end;
        print ' '
        set @i = @i + 1
    end;
```

expected code output

```
* 
* * 
* * * 
* * * * 
* * * * *
```

but i am getting not output like this 
any help is appreciated!!
faced some questions similar to this hence asking in t-sql instead of java
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you need to change school. Whoever gave you this homework assignment failed to realize that T-SQL is not a programming language.
This is a pretty standard exercise for nesting loops with programming languages - but in SQL, you should avoid using loops, let alone nested loops.

That being said, each `print` will start a new line, so instead of nested loops, use a single loop (meaning print one row in each iteration), and to make the strings grow, use `replicate`.

```
declare @n int = 5 --number of lines
declare @i int=1
while (@i <= @n)
    begin
        print REPLICATE('* ', @i)
        set @i = @i + 1
    end;
```

And just for fun, here is a better way to do that in SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @str varchar(40) = '';

WITH T(n) AS
(
    SELECT TOP 5 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID)
    FROM sys.objects
)

SELECT  @str += REPLICATE('* ', n) 
    + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
FROM T 

PRINT @Str
```

And a non-RBAR solution based on the same `T` cte:

```
SELECT @Str = 
(
    SELECT REPLICATE('* ', n) + CHAR(10)
    FROM T 
    FOR XML PATH('')
)
```

Comment: I failed to understand why use LAG again,this will slow down performance.Only this much is sufficient.@str += REPLICATE('* ', n) 
    + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10).Also your second solution is better than RBAR

Comment: @KumarHarsh Actually, you are correct. The lag is meaningless here. Editing that out. However, even the second solution is RBAR - since for every row in the select statement the `@str` parameter get's updated.

Comment: @KumarHarsh I've also added a non-RBAR solution.